# Wallet Balance does not match Transaction Total

Tags: balance

Obviously, I am a newbie.....I have made several "buys" on Coinbase and the Wallet balance does not match the transaction totals - they are off a considerable percentage amount. Am I looking at it wrong or what?

Comment: Without some level of detail, it's impossible to tell if there is a problem or you are just "looking at it wrong".  Add the details to your question via the [edit] link.